What was the Purpose of God's Delayed Making of the Human Epidermis, Dermis, and Hypodermis?
After sinning, Adam and Eve realized they were naked, exposed, and sewed together makeshift fig leaf coverings. Apparently, this covering barely did the job because when God confronts them, Adam claims he hid from God because he was naked.
Eventually per Genesis 3:21 God makes garments of skin for Adam and his wife and clothed them. Per the Ibn Ezra in the name of ‘some say’ (Genesis 3:21) what this means is that Adam and Eve literally had no skin until God ‘clothed them’ with such. (They must have placed the earlier fig leaves on top of muscle, bone and flesh). Sounds very sci-fi!

כתנו' עור. יש אומר כי בתחלה היו עצם ובשר ועתה קרם עליה' עור.
GARMENTS OF SKIN. Some say that Adam and Eve originally consisted of bone and flesh, and God now covered them with skin.

But, presumably, the act found in Genesis 3:21 was to provide Adam and Eve with a proper covering thereby mitigating their nakedness/naked shame. (And the verse does use the words "clothe them.") How does anatomical skin conceal nakedness? This indeed is the Radak’s presumption and question:

איך היו מלובשים בעבור זה, ואיך נכסת ערותם בזה?
How would they be clothed by this? How would their genitals have been covered?

What is an answer to the Radak's question?

If the baseline level of nakedness was having no skin at all, why do we assume that exposed genitals was even a problem?
